# Are there any things I should remove from an Xcode project for security purposes when uploading to Github?

Tags: ios, xcode, github

I've decided to upload all of my apps to Github, what should I consider when doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Commercial apps or open source?

Comment: They are all on the Appstore. However, I am only publishing the free ones.

Comment: I recommend going with private repositories and everything will be fine. Unlimited private ones with just $7 monthly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making this community wiki so others can add to the list as needed.

As a general rule, never commit generated files. Only commit files that are required to build the project.

Don't add any private information such as keys, ids, or passwords that shouldn't be known to the public.

Don't add anything you are prohibited from making public. This might apply if you have pictures, videos or other resources you have permission to use from another 3rd party. They may not want you to share these resources.

Make sure all of your source files have desired copyright notices and add a LICENSE file to the root of the project. Then people know what they are allowed to do with all of your code.

Assume lots of people will copy all of your hard work whether you want them to or not.